# NCSA request handler doesn't work in pax-web 1.1.4

Tags: java, pax, pax-web

I try to enable NCSA request logging in pax-web 1.1.4. The recommended [way to do it](http://team.ops4j.org/browse/PAXWEB-269) doesn't work. The file was created but it stays empty. Looking in source code I found that pax web implementation of Jetty server passes requests to JettyServerHandlerCollection which assumes that every handler should correspond a context. So it looks impossible for me just to use org.ops4j.pax.web.log.ncsa.* options.

Am I missing something or this functionality doesn't work in pax web? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's a bug in Pax-Web and has been filed on [PAXWEB-416](http://team.ops4j.org/browse/PAXWEB-416)